# Concatenate the maps on typescript produce property not define error

Tags: typescript

I need to concatenate two jsons using the typescript concatenation function as follow

```
function mapConcat(){
    let mapABC = { a: 5, b: 6, c:3};
    let mapAll = {...mapABC , d:8};
}
```

but while I compile this function, My typescript compiler producing the following error.

```
TS2339: Property 'mapABC' does not exist on type '{ d: number; a: number; b: number; c: number; }'.
```

From this error I have understood mapABC is not defined. But I have defined as local property inside it. What wrongs with this concatenation

Comment: What version of typescript do you have? Object spread was added in **2.1** and this works just fine in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20mapConcat()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mapABC%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%205%2C%20b%3A%206%2C%20c%3A3%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mapAll%20%3D%20%7B...mapABC%20%2C%20d%3A8%7D%3B%0A%7D)

Comment: my one is 2.1.5